# What activates auto fire?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As a hunter, I have a basic attack that will use my weapon for low damage every couple of seconds. I know that if I right click on a hostile, it will start, but are there any other ways to activate it?

Comment: You can disable auto attack I believe

Comment: How do I prevent it from acitvating (so I can target a boss, then once he is agroed on tank, start firing with already having targeted him)?

Comment: I'll find out today and get back to you.  Last I remember it was in Interface/Options.

Comment: There's a `Shoot` (`Attack` for classes with melee weapons) spell in the `General` tab of your spellbook that toggles it on/off, you can use it for fine-grained control over what to autoattack and what not to. Or use the `/startattack` and `/stopattack` commands

Comment: Consider instead: target the tank, and then press `F` (`/assist`) to switch to his target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any ability you have that does damage to an enemy will also activate your autoattack, unless it specifically states in the tooltip that it "turns off your attack"; such abilities *deactivate* your autoattack.

If you want to be able to select targets without attacking them, go into your Interface > Controls options and turn off "Interact on Left Click". You can then left click an enemy to select it without attacking.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the `T` key should do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is "auto attack"

Using a ability will start your auto attack.

Comment: Any ability will start it?

Answer (score 0):

Most of your shots will activate your Autoshot however some of your abilities won't. Especially Pet abilities like A murder of Crows, Stampede and Dire Beast will not start your Autoshot. For some reason Glaive Toss also doesn't start it which makes it an excellent pre-cast ability for Survival Hunters (Glaive Toss has a projectile speed of 18 y/s).

To start attacking a target you have 3 options: You can Right-click it, you can use an ability which triggers your autoshot or you can use a `/startattack` macro. To turn off your autoattack simply use a `/stopattack` macro.

There's also some weird behavior with the `/stopcasting` macros. Examples:

```
#showtooltip Disengage
/stopcasting
/cast Disengage
```

Will simply cause you to finish your cast without disengaging and stops your autoattack

```
#showtooltip Disengage
/stopcasting
/stopcasting 
/cast Disengage
```

Will instantly interrupt your cast and your will disengage while your autoattack remains active.

I have absolutely no Idea why stopcasting works that way and whether it's intentional or a bug (i guess it's considered a feature now) but it's something many hunters don't know.